# Is it possible to lock the S/PDIF output sample rate to 44.1 on a Creative External Sound Blaster Live! SB0490?

Tags: audio, sound-card, creative

Is it possible to lock the S/PDIF output sample rate to 44.1 on a Creative External Sound Blaster Live! SB0490?

I have recently attached my SB0490 to a new Windows 7 computer with the latest drivers from Creative.
Previously I had it connected to a Windows XP computer and there was a program in the Creative group of the Start-menu that allowed me to configure the sample rate of the output.

In Windows 7, the only place I can find to make such a setting is the “Shared Mode” “Default Format” under the Advanced Tab of the SPDIF-Out settings. I'm not sure if this is the same thing or not.

[image]

I changed the setting to 44.1 but when I opened a recording program (GoldWave) the output changed back to 48k. I had to change the same setting in the “Line-in/Mic-in” settings to get the output to revert back to 44.1k.

[image]

It's a problem for me because whenever the sample rate changes, it causes all my downstream devices to hick-up while they re-synchronize and that sounds very loud and bad.

I also found the “Supported Formats” settings, but they do not seem to have an effect on the S/PDIF output sample rate.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Sound Blaster works natively in 48000 Hz

The EMU10K chip introduces a lot of distortions when it downsample ( dunno if upsample is possible above 48khz) This is done automatically depending on the source. if you're listening to a 44.1khz sample then the soundblaster will be forced to downsample from 48 to 44.1 which is not done correctly as i said above.

So the best way is to not change anything. just let your soundcard work in 48000 Hz.